# How to access the photos of a plugged in iPhone from macOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I want tor write a macOS Application and I'm stuck accessing the data of an plugged in iPhone? It is not handled like a normal USB drive (obviously).
Does somebody have a hint?
As I'm always getting answers related to iOS, can anybody recommend a resource for macOS development?

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageKitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004907

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: [ImageCaptureCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/02Overview/02Overview.html) does the job! There is actually a sample application provided by apple [SimpleCameraBrowser](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SimpleCameraBrowser/Introduction/Intro.html).

Another sample for using the framework [Creating an Application Using ImageCaptureCore](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/CreatinganApplicationUsingImageCaptureCore/CreatinganApplicationUsingImageCaptureCore.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005196-CH5-SW5)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is the best solution, but you can try using [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice) to explore the device file system (even for non-jailbroken devices). Keep in mind that this library is licensed as GPL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as there are plenty of tools out there, there must be some lib/framework that makes accessing more easy? Anybody another idea?

Comment: Just to crealify - I want just access to the photos stored on the iPhone. Other filesystem access is not needed...

Comment: Well, I am glad you found a solution :).